# get package name of current application which is open on screen? Not working in lollipop?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-keypad

I am working with custom keyboard ,I need current package name when keyboard is open . This keyboard will be open with different different application ,so i need that application package name which is open currently.
I am using following code but its not working properly.

```
  ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
            .getPackageName();
```

Comment: i am getting com.android.launcher for all other application

Answer (score 2):

I know this is too late but above answer not working, and i found proper answer, so i write this,

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
     String mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
}
else{ 
     String mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
}
```

Comment: I have used your code but gives me the package name of my app each time, It's not giving me the name of any other app's package name which ever I'm opening. I'm testing on MarshMallow

Answer (score 1):

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
 Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
 ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
 String packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

You will need the following permission on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: i have implemented this code too but with other application i am getting com.android.launcher always

Comment: @DevelopmentELGroup: did you got any solution ?